# Capture image without permission with Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to let the user take a picture (from the gallery or from a camera app) with Android 6.0.

Because I don't need to control the camera, I wanted to use an intent as describe here:

> However, if you don't need such control, you can just use an ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent to request an image. When you start the intent, the user is prompted to choose a camera app (if there isn't already a default camera app), and that app takes the picture. The camera app returns the picture to your app's onActivityResult() method.

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

But for this **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE**, you need to fill the extra **"MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT"** which is an Uri to a temp file (without this param I will have only a thumbnail). This temp file must be into the external storage (to be accessible by the camera app). You need the permission **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** to create a file on the external storage.

So it's not possible to capture an image through native dialogs/apps without the **permission android.permission.CAMERA** or **android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**. Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: You are welcome to try passing a `content://` `Uri` in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` pointing to a `ContentProvider` that you write, where you can accept the data. I have not tried this, and my guess is that there will be a bunch of camera apps that will not be expecting such a value and will choke on it.

Comment: did you ever find a work around for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible if you on android 4.4+, you can specify MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, to be a file under your **package-specific
directories**

> Starting in Android 4.4, the owner, group and modes of files on
>   external storage devices are now synthesized based on directory
>   structure. This enables apps to manage their **package-specific
>   directories** on external storage without requiring they hold the broad
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. **For example, the app with package
>   name com.example.foo can now freely access
>   Android/data/com.example.foo/ on external storage devices with no
>   permissions.** These synthesized permissions are accomplished by
>   wrapping raw storage devices in a FUSE daemon.

https://source.android.com/devices/storage/

Comment: Have you actually tried this? This gives YOUR app access to the directory, but not the CAMERA app, which is the problem.

Comment: @Derek Fung can you share an example project?

Comment: Camera doesn't have access to app private cache dir directory. @Jonathan Aste's solution is working.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "yourPicture.jpg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, url);
```

This gives you access to an "external" storage writable for camera apps in this case, but the files are just visible from your app. 
To learn a little bit more about storage spaces in android see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C28pvd2plBA

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This is the only working solution I found so far that doesn't break on Android 6. :)

Comment: Working! No need for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Thanks! In `onActivityResult` you will get `RESULT_OK` and `data == null`. In this case you should either read a file from path (variable `uri`), or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043222/how-to-get-full-size-picture-and-thumbnail-from-camera-in-the-same-intent. You have to get permission for file reading on API >= 23.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible without either of the `CAMERA` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

You can create a temporary in your app's cache directory, and give other apps access to it. That makes the file writeable by the camera app:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("photo", ".jpg", context.getCacheDir());
tempFile.setWritable(true, false);
```

Now you just need to pass this file as the output file for the camera intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTempFile));  // pass temp file
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

Note: the file Uri won't be passed to you in the Activity result, you'll have to keep a reference to the tempFile and retrieve it from there.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore when targeting Marshmallow.

Comment: this option seems promising, anyone have any feedback with regards to compatibility?

Comment: Doesn't work. Camera app doesn't have access to app cache dir.

Answer (score 1):

I used `content://` with `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics), and used external camera app by ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, which is not supposed to require any permission.

But, it seems that if the app's manifest uses the `android.permission.CAMERA` permission, then opening an external camera app does require camera permission. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992542/7356258) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32789027/7356258).