# Android: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission not accepted by device

Tags: android

I'm having a rather strange problem with an Android app I'm writing.

In my app, I use an intent to tell the phone's camera app to take a picture for me. After I take this picture, I want to register the newly taken photo with the device's MediaStore content provider in order to make it show up in the regular "gallery" app.

To do this, I know I need the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but even when it's in my manifest I get a permission denied exception. What do I have to do to get this permission? I'm running Android 6.0.1.

Here's my permissions XML in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here's the code that causes the exception:

```
       // insert photo into phone's main photo content provider
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

        try {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(cr, photoFile.getPath(),
                    "Image Capture", "Custom Image capture");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException foe) {
            Log.e(DEBUG, foe.getMessage());
        }
```

And here's the exception I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=2436, uid=10041 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

**EDIT**: I should probably mention:

Right now my app uses `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`, which returns the path `/sdcard/Android/data/<package>/files/Pictures` to save it's photos. I want them to go where the camera app normally puts them, in `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`.

Comment: Is this running on an android marshmallow?

Comment: You don't need the storage permission - you can write the file to a directory returned by [getExternalMediaDirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalMediaDirs()) on Lollipop+ devices.

Comment: Yes I am running on Mashmallow 6.0.1.

Comment: what is your targetSdk?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` to the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as well. Your code should look like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with respect to you requesting the permission but not being granted the permission by the user. Have a look at my answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/35574084/529691

And see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should promt the user to provide you permission:

```
    int externalPermissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (externalPermissionCheck==-1){
        askPermissionStorage();
    }


private void askPermissionStorage() {
    //for media
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.
            WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //insert explanation
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //if you want to explaian to the user

        } else {//if no explanation needed
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new
                            String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is for save the picture\video
and this is for the camera permission:

```
    int cameraPermissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (cameraPermissionCheck == -1) {
        askPermissionCamera();
    }
private void askPermissionCamera() {
    //for camera
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.
            CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //insert explanation
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            //if you want to explaian to the user

        } else {//if no explanation needed
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new
                            String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}
```