# Android Studio App Crash, Related To OnClick and startActivityForResult

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, camera

I am learning how to make a simple camera app on Android Studio at the moment. When I click the 'camera' button, the app crashes. I can't seem to pinpoint what is causing the app to crash. In logcat, it states that 'startActivityForResult' might be the cause...but it looks normal to me.

I made sure that the camera button id matches the java file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code so far.

Main_Activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button cam_button;
ImageView imageView;
static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    cam_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cam_button);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageV);

    cam_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}


private File getFile() {
    File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");
    if(folder.exists())
        folder.mkdir();

    File imageFile = new File("cameraImage.jpg");

    return imageFile;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cameraImage.jpg";
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
}}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="camera"
    android:id="@+id/cam_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageV"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

This is what I copied from the logcat:

> 06-24 21:30:45.769 21481-21481/com.sugarcoder.cameraapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.sugarcoder.cameraapp, PID: 21481
>                                                                         java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3
>   cmp=com.motorola.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list
>   U:file:///cameraImage.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{b5b85f2
>   21481:com.sugarcoder.cameraapp/u0a121} (pid=21481, uid=10121) with
>   revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
>                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
>                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2696)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1574)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3921)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3881)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
>                                                                             at
>   com.sugarcoder.cameraapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
>                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
>                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: Post your crash log

Comment: I included what I saw in logcat.

Comment: using marshmallow 6.0 ??

Comment: I suppose this is what you asked for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35574084/1867608

Comment: Yes, using Marshmallow 6.0

I added a ton of permissions already....so that article doesn't help unfortunately. For example, I added camera, internet, write_external_storage, read_external_storage, and access_network_state. 

I also added users-feature android.hardware.camera.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you accept the permission?.

Comment: I just learned that I needed to do that in the app info. Thank you so much for the tip! Seems I learned it the same time you commented. :)

Comment: glad you've solved it :).

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I found out the issue is that I had to actually go into the app info for the app on the phone, and turn on the permission. Thanks for all your help, folks! :)