# Android M - camera permissions issue

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-securityexception

I'm encountering the known issue of permissions in Android M.
When attempting the open the camera it get the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent 
{ act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity } 
from ProcessRecord{834e30b 8608:il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2/u0a126} (pid=8608, uid=10126) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

Here is my complete code, it includes a workaround that I've found here and worked for others, but for some reason fails for me.

```
public class ReportTaskStatus extends AppCompatActivity{

private Task tastToEdit;
private RadioButton acceptrb;
private RadioButton statusrb;
private TextView label;
private List<ParseObject> tsks=null;

public Uri fileUri;
private int CAMERA_REQUEST = 100;
private int Gallary_REQUEST = 101;
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_task_status);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent i = getIntent();


    tastToEdit = (Task)i.getSerializableExtra("task");
    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.categorylabel);
    label.append(" "+tastToEdit.getTask_catg().toString());

    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prioritylabel);
    label.append(" "+tastToEdit.getPriority().toString());

    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationlabel);
    label.append(" " + Location.fromInteger(tastToEdit.getTsk_location()).toString());

    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.duetimelabel);

    if(tastToEdit.getDueDate()!=null)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        label.append(" " + (sdf.format(tastToEdit.getDueDate())));
        label.append(" " + (sdft.format(tastToEdit.getDueDate())));
    }

    Task_Status tsk_stts = tastToEdit.getTask_sts();

    if(tsk_stts==Task_Status.WAITING)
    {
        statusrb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.waitingstatusRBtn);
        statusrb.setChecked(true);
    }
    if(tsk_stts==Task_Status.INPROGESS)
    {
        statusrb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.inprogstatusRBtn);
        statusrb.setChecked(true);
    }
    if(tsk_stts==Task_Status.DONE)
    {
        statusrb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.donestatusRBtn);
        statusrb.setChecked(true);
    }
    //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusgroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.donestatusRBtn);
            if(rb.isChecked())
            {
                Log.w("donestatusRBtn","donestatusRBtn");
                openCamera();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void Camerapermission() {
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ReportTaskStatus.this
            ,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ReportTaskStatus.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ReportTaskStatus.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
}

void openCamera() {
    try {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch ( requestCode ) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            for( int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++ ) {
                if( grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    Log.d( "Permissions", "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i] );
                } else if( grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ) {
                    Log.d( "Permissions", "Permission Denied: " + permissions[i] );
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        default: {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Permissions for manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are not calling your `Camerapermission()` method, at least in terms of the code shown in your question.

Second, you are allowing the user to do something strange with a `RadioButton` that triggers a call to `openCamera()`, without checking to see that you have permission to use the camera. For example, you could use `checkSelfPermission()` to see if you have permission, and only enable that `RadioButton` if you do.

You may wish to read more about [the runtime permission system](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to call 'Camerapermission()'. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Reference in doc:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using device with Android M, so give the appropriate permissions to the app: **Settings -> Apps -> your app**

If this does not help look at this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789027/android-m-camera-intent-permission-bug#answer-32856112).