# Can't get permission for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in Android M

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am new to android devlopement. I created a simple demo for picking a 1 pic from camera & one from gallery,& set them to imageview..

As well as concern about gallery, all works properly. But when i click on camera button,it doesn't open camera..
This issue i facing in only marshmallow devices. I search alot about requestpermissions() & onRequestPermissionResult() method. But i not able to understand.

So i want to know how to get permission for accessing a camera specially for android m devices?

Here is the code for both method relating to camera permission..
[call of requestpermissions() method[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztlTJ.png)

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android M Camera Intent + permission bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789027/android-m-camera-intent-permission-bug)

Comment: Maybe same  @ Devendra Singh... But i am not able to understand that..Is there anything easy?

Answer (score 0):

```
    https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=tedpermission use this library for runtime permission for marshmallow device


    repositories {

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPermission:v1.0.11'
    }







  PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    };






  new TedPermission(this)
    .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
    .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
    .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)//set permission
    .check();
```

setPermission according to your need in Ted permission ...

Comment: Please, add code example. Now this is low quality answer.