# CodenameOne: Capture.capturePhoto() requests wrong permission?

Tags: codenameone

CodenameOne's `Capture.capturePhoto(1000, -1)` seems to work fine with Android targetSDKVersion 21 permissions. But on 23 it wrongly requests a

> Allow [...] to access photos media, and files on your device?

permission from the user, but then fails because of the `android.permission.CAMERA` missing.

(The simulator in lack of a camera requests media files instead - could there be something mixed up?)

UPDATE (DDMS output)

```
08-09 15:13:47.866: W/ActivityManager(1676): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x4000003 cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/XXX/IMG_20170809_151347.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{f736f3f 20079:com.XXX/u0a338} (pid=20079, uid=10338) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
08-09 15:13:47.876: W/System.err(20079): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x4000003 cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/XXX/IMG_20170809_151347.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{f736f3f 20079:com.XXX/u0a338} (pid=20079, uid=10338) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
08-09 15:13:47.896: E/ConfigFileUtils(3071): Failed to read config file: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_modulesets.pb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3131)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1540)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneActivity.startActivityForResult(CodenameOneActivity.java:576)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at com.codename1.impl.android.c.a(AndroidImplementation.java:5869)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at com.codename1.u.p.b(Display.java:3109)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at com.codename1.b.a.a(Capture.java:77)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at com.codename1.b.a.a(Capture.java:125)
08-09 15:13:47.906: W/System.err(20079):    at com.grandgreat.XXX.ai.b(SettingsForm.java:98)
```

(SettingsForm.java:98 `String path = Capture.capturePhoto(1000, -1);` )

Comment: I suggest providing the failure that you got e.g. stack traces DDMS output etc.

Comment: I suspect that this old question is related with this recent issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2409

Answer (score 0):

This should have worked since we use an `Intent` which does all the work of capturing so we don't even request that permission. See the code [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java#L5847-L5870).

However, as explained by this stack overflow question [Android M Camera Intent + permission bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789027/android-m-camera-intent-permission-bug)

If the app has a camera permission the intent might fail to prevent what appears to be a misbehavior. Again a horrible edge case of the intent system...

The workaround is indeed to prompt for camera permission which we will add for the update tomorrow (August 11th 2017).

Comment: I added the DDMS output to the question

Comment: Thanks, it's now clear why it breaks for you and not for others, it depends on the existing app permissions which are probably different here. Updated post with answer

Comment: I reverted this and did some more reading. I don't see why this is failing for you in the first place. What do you have in your build hints?