# revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

Tags: android

I get ERROR `revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA`

I was using camera permission on manifest

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    switch (actionCode) {
        case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
            File f = null;

            try {
                f = setUpPhotoFile();
                mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                f = null;
                mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } // switch

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}
```

and error like this:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.mobile.lunatique.photo, PID: 3590
                      java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:file:///KTP_42342.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{2fbbd91 3590:com.mobile.lunatique.photo/u0a60} (pid=3590, uid=10060) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
                          at com.mobile.lunatique.photo.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.java:254)
                          at com.mobile.lunatique.photo.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:33)
                          at com.mobile.lunatique.photo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:321)
                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3590 SIG: 9
```

anyone can help me??

Comment: Post stacktrace.

Comment: Too much irrelevant code, too little relevant stuff like stacktrace and explanations.

Comment: In Marshamallow, user should activate the permission at run time. See here : 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html.

Or you can set your targetSdkVersion in the gradle to 22 (It is not recommended but it works)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Here's how I solved this problem.

Contrary to what most answers say, **REMOVE** this from your Manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

**Why?**

Starting Android M (API 23), if your app has *CAMERA* permission declared in the manifest, then, it needs that *CAMERA* permission to be *GRANTED* in order to access *ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE*
etc... too (which normally do not require the *CAMERA* permission on their own). If not, then it automatically raises a *SecurityException*.

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║                      Usage                      ║ Permissions needed ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE                            ║ none               ║
║ ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE                            ║ none               ║
║ INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA                ║ none               ║
║ android.hardware.camera2                        ║ CAMERA             ║
║ android.hardware.camera2 + ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE ║ CAMERA             ║
║ android.hardware.camera2 + ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE ║ CAMERA             ║
║ ...                                             ║ ...                ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

*Above table is only for API 23+*

**tl;dr What to do?**

**Option 1-** If you only use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` etc... 
Remove the `CAMERA` permission from manifest and you would be fine

**Option 2-** If you use other `CAMERA` functions: 
Check for `CAMERA` permission at runtime and only start the intent when the permission is available

Comment: Man I searched for this for hours! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thnaks a Lot. I was stuck 4 to 5 hours.

Comment: Can u please elaborate why need to remove camera permission? @Kathir

Comment: @PawanSoni I have reformatted my answer. Please let me know if it's better now.

Comment: I have no sense of this behavior ...

Comment: We are using a library that uses `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` which can crop images from file store in the device storage or images captured using camera. However it is crashing (same as above issue) when `CAMERA` permission is added in app module. But we need `CAMERA` for other feature of the app not just for the image cropping library. Are you saying we should ask for `CAMERA` permission also when using the library to avoid the issue?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Yes, that should probably fix the crash (if that was the actual reason behind the crash)

Comment: @Kathir thanks, by the way may I know how are you able to produce that command line table?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS I generated that table based off the behaviour back then. It's not from the documentation

Comment: Brilliant answer! Correct and no-side-effect answer!

Answer (score 18):

Hi lunatique aldebaran,

> First of all you need to add the following permission in manifest.xml
>   file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

> Check whether the android device is Marshmallow or not. If its android
>   M or greater version then use the following code to get camera
>   permission dynamically.
>
> Before android M dont want to get dynamic permission.
>
> check if the user grant the permission. If user not granted permission
>   then request the camera permission access.

```
private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
```

> After requesting the permission alert will display to ask permission
>   contains allow and deny options. After clicking action we can get
>   result of the request with the following method.

```
@Override

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
```

Comment: THIS would be the accepted answer. Very complete. Thank you.

Comment: The point is that taking a picture via intent should not require this permission at all, but like the accepted answer mentions, somehow the permission must be granted if you have it in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AppCompatActivity` instead, of extending your MainActivity. And also please, include stacktrace.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//......
}
```

Oh, sorry. With stacktrace it's clearly seen main problem. `android.permission.CAMERA`. For making request, you should create permission check. Please, check  [This Example](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en), to create Permission checking.

**Example:**

1) Include to Activity.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

2) Ensure you request permissions from the user:

```
if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                                                LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION );
}
```

3) Check in RunTime

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
             ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revoke Permission....It Simply say's you have invoked the permission again so no need to write permission for Camera again in Manifest file ......

Instead you just....need to write two line....to READ and Write External Storage which are enough to run your program


it's enough to run your program

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but it looks like Android has a bug with this. When you add camera permission to AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

You have to grant permission for it even you want to use external application for taking a photo. Deleting it from manifest has solved problem with **SecurityException**.